# Derivation of the Binding Energy of Atoms without Kinetic Considerations and Relativistic Corrections

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation, binding-energy

The question [Relativistic corrections to the binding energy of atoms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699184/relativistic-corrections-to-the-binding-energy-of-atoms) is answered with a brief chronology of ideas about the binding energy of the electron to the atomic nucleus. (The emphasis in the quotations is mine.)

> Basically it is a combination of **kinetic energy** and electrostatic potential energy, which comes about as a kind of equilibrium …

> Relativistic corrections come in three steps. First one can modify the non-relativistic theory by adding **corrections to the formula for kinetic energy** and things like that. But a better way, the second step, is to replace Schrodinger's equation with Dirac's equation for the system. Dirac's equation takes relativity into account right from the start. …  It gives the answer where (,,) and the total **angular momentum** …

> Finally, the full modern treatment … has to adopt the … quantum electrodynamics or QED. The calculation involves a sequence of integrals which account for all possible ways the electron and proton can exchange energy and **momentum**.

Now one can associate the momentum with the spin and assign to the spin the exclusive function of a spatial orientation (thus no rotational motion). All, what has to do with the originally assumed orbital motion, was outsourced in constants.

For me it would be therefore only consistent to derive the formula of the binding energy anew without the stain of the outdated assumption of the orbital motion and to teach this then also in such a way.

Is there such a derivation and with how many corrections, to calculate for all atoms (or even better all molecular bonds) the observed wavelengths?

Comment: There seems to be a misunderstanding. Modern calculations in QM don't assume the electron is a little ball flying around. When people say "kinetic energy", they mean "the kinetic energy term in the Hamiltonian", which depends on the spatial derivatives of the wavefunction, and only reduces to the usual "ball flying around" kinetic energy in the classical limit.

Answer (score 0):

For hydrogen, to get an answer at about part per thousand precision, use
$$
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2 \mu} \nabla^2 \psi - \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \psi = E \psi.
$$
This is the time-independent Schrodinger equation. The first term on the left represents kinetic energy, the second represents potential energy. $\psi(x,y,z)$ is a function of position. $E$ on the right is a scalar, it is the energy you want to calculate. $-E$ is the binding energy. $\mu = m M/(m+M)$ is the reduced mass. You solve by guessing a suitable form for $\psi$, proving that it is indeed a solution, and extracting $E$. You then use some further arguments to prove it is the lowest possible $E$. In the present example the form to use is $\psi \propto \exp(-r/a)$ with $a$ a constant to be derived
and $r = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^{1/2}$.

For other atoms it gets a lot more complicated. For $N$ electrons you have a partial differential equation in $3N$ variables (the $x,y,z$ coordinates of $N$   electrons), involving sums over all the interactions. There is no analytical solution. You need a textbook on atomic physics to learn about all the steps involved in getting solutions of increasing accuracy. And that is before we get into intrinsic angular momentum (spin) which leads to magnetic dipole moments and further interactions $\ldots$.